# Animate newly added items to my listview?

Tags: java, android

I have a adapter that displays the SMS / MMS messages on the phone. I am trying to animate a new message being either sent or received. Instead of the message item just appearing in the list I want to animate a new message into the listview. Here is a video of something similar to what I am wanting to accomplish

[Listview Animation Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LFDdgRncLQQ)

I know that I could apply the animation into the getView() method of the adapter, but I want to only animate the new messages. Anyone know of a possible way for me to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that using [Layout Transitions](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html). [This link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2011/11/android-40-graphics-and-animations.html) also may help you. 
But this class is available only on API Level 11+, so if you want to provide compatibility to earlier android API Levels, you have to try something different.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I applied the android:animateLayoutChanges="true" property to my listview, but it only animates the items when I move up and down the listview. I want to be able to be all the way at the bottom of the listview and then when I get a new message, there will be an animation for the new message.

Comment: try something like "listView.smoothScrollToPosition(adapter.getCount() - 1);"
This will scroll your listview to the last position.